# Is my battery indeed has 12 cells/7800mAh?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I've ordered 12 cell 7200mAh battery for my notebook HP HDX18t. When I received the battery it says 14.4V/7800mAh ( and not 7200mAh like it was stated).

1 - According to [this](http://www.createchy.com/news.asp?fid=294&id=717) site  the number of cells in this battery is `7800mAh/2600mAh * 14.4v / 3.7v = 11.6` cells.

I installed BatteryCare program and this is what it shows

[image: battery info]

2 - According to [this](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/electric/mah-to-wh.htm) site the mAh of battery (converting from mWh) is `96768 / 14.4 = 6720mAh`

My question is

a - Should I consider 11.6 that I got in (1) to 12 or 11 cells?

b - From (2) I didn't get neither 7800mAh nor 7200mAh but **6720**. Does it means that the battery I got is not new or I should wait until I will recharge&charge it several times and after that it should increase the number in Total Capacity?

Comment: Sorry but consumer electronics like laptop batteries are not a good fit for this site, [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) is better for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

1. 7800 mAh = 2400 mAh * 3... you have exactly 12 cells, connected 3 in parallel (increasing current) and 4 in series (increasing voltage).
2. The voltage doesn't stay constant during discharge, so you cannot just say `96768 / 14.4`.  Also, capacity will decrease as the battery ages.  (But, your software is convinced this battery is very new; this will reflect the metadata stored in the control circuit, not the cells themselves).
    Because the total capacity you got is greater than the "design capacity", do not expect your battery to "break-in" or otherwise improve beyond what you see now.